# Show dates according to a selected day of week

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I have a problem where when I select a day from a spinner (ex. Wednesday), I want to show only the dates of Wednesday in DatePickerDialog. How can I make that happen? I want to disable other dates and enable the days that match the selected spinner item.

[Selected Item on Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZinJ5.png)

[Dates on DatePickerDialog but I wanted only to show dates according to selected spinner item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lvsf.png)

I'm using `MaterialDateTimePicker`. Is there a way to make this happen or a library that will make this happen?

Comment: This is not possible with native `DatePickerDialog` unless you are using a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use `MaterialDateTimePicker`, you can select the acceptable dates  for the picker with the method `setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)`